# Can a Javascript library conditionally import a module only if its parent application depends on it?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, rollupjs

Say I have a library called `library`, which is used in an application called `app` - the latter of which is a front-end application using e.g. Webpack, and npm for dependency management.

What I'd like to be able to do is for `library` to do a call `import('sibling').then(/* ... */).catch(/* ... */)`, where once piece of code is executed if `app` has a dependency on `sibling`, and another piece of code when `app` does *not* list `sibling` as a dependency.

For illustration, the directory structure:

```
app
|
| - node_modules
| | - library # does a call import('sibling')
| | - sibling # might not be present
```

Is that possible today, and if so, under what conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this *is* actually possible, but the way I was doing it caused it to break. Specifically, `library` first set `const moduleName = 'sibling';`, and only then did a call to `import(moduleName)`. However, at least Webpack (which I was using for `app`) seems to resolve modules during build time, rather than at runtime. In other words, it's specifically looking for calls to `import('sibling')` during build, and then making that point to the correct module.

In other words, `import()` should either get a file name as a parameter (regardless of whether that's the result of an expression), or a module name as a literal string. Then the set up I described in the question should just work, at least with Webpack.